# matplotlib time on x axis from datetime json

Tags: python, matplotlib, azure-functions

I am fairly new to Python and trying to build some helper Azure Functions function in Python to draw time series charts.

I am sending the following data to the function:

```
{
    "x": [
        "2021-04-07T11:38:51.959Z",
        "2021-04-07T11:39:01.964Z",
       .....
    ]
    "y": [
        39.71353912353515,
        39.71353912353515,
        39.71353912353515,
        39.702688217163086,
        .....
        99804688
    ]
}
```

I am trying to process it with the following code:

```
import logging
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import AutoDateFormatter, AutoDateLocator
import azure.functions as func
import base64

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    req_body = req.get_json()
    x = req_body.get('x')
    y = req_body.get('y')
    x1 = req_body.get('x1')
    y1 = req_body.get('y1')
    dt_series = pd.Series(x)
    dt_list = pd.to_datetime(dt_series)
    x_list = dt_list.values.tolist()
    logging.info(x_list)
    sizeX = len(x)/8
    xtick_locator = AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=15)
    xtick_formatter = AutoDateFormatter(xtick_locator)
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xtick_locator)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xtick_formatter)
    plt.figure(figsize=(sizeX,6))
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(x_list, y)
```

and a result looks like this:

[image]

I would like the timestamps to be displayed like on the following:

[image]

How to achieve that? The current translation to time does not seem to work at all....

After a suggestion from Bastian `(plt.plot(dt_list, y))` it got parsed, but now maxticks is not working as the result contains 9 ticks instead of 7 making the chart crowded:
[image]

How to fix that either?

Comment: Use the list of datetime values: plt.plot(dt_list, y)

Comment: Great:-) I edited the post - this time I am wondering how to manage the crowd on x axis due to number of ticks

Comment: remove plt.clf(), here you clear everything you have set previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use [fig.autofmt_xdate()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html?highlight=autofmt#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate)?

See:

```py
from scipy.stats import skewnorm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
a = 4
x = np.linspace(skewnorm.ppf(0.01, a), skewnorm.ppf(0.99, a), 50)
d = pd.date_range("2021-04-06 12:00:00", "2021-04-06 16:00:00", 50)

ax.plot(d, skewnorm.pdf(x, a), 'b-', label='skewnorm pdf')

# from matplotlib.dates import AutoDateFormatter, AutoDateLocator
# xtick_locator = AutoDateLocator(minticks=3, maxticks=15)
# xtick_formatter = AutoDateFormatter(xtick_locator)
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xtick_locator)
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xtick_formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib output]